# Angular form Input box being unstable with barcode reader in a simple form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple view;

```
<form ng-submit="ctrl.check()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input">
</form>
<div>
  <span ng-repeat="input in ctrl.log">{{input}}<br></span>
</div>
```

Connected to the controller;

```
app.controller('verify', [..., function(...) {
  var ctrl = this;
  // some variables omitted here
  ctrl.input = '';
  ctrl.log = [];
  ctrl.check = function()
  {
    ctrl.log.unshift(ctrl.input);
    // some logic omitted here
  };
}]);
```

But when the user scans a barcode containing the string "`123456789.`" repeatedly, the log object contains randomly cropped values.
From a screenshot, this is what I see:

```
12345678
1234567
123
```

Scanning the barcode in notepad works perfectly.

I am struggling to see what is happening here, but my only suspicion at this point is that the ng-model binding is being slower at updating the model than the form is to respond to the enter key, thus causing the submit to happen before the model has been updated.

Is this a known issue with angular/Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You might be able to control the timing of your form through `ng-model-options` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#!/

Comment: the only thing in that page that seemed relevant to me was "debounce", but setting that to 0 did not resolve the issue, according to the user.

Comment: I have now tried adding a new function that runs check after a 2 second delay and bound that to ng-submit, to no avail.